# Single line nested for loop in Python

Tags: python

I've got an object that looks something like this:

```
obj = {
    "outer_list": [
        {
            "inner_list_1": ["string1", "string2"]
        },
        {
            "inner_list_2": ["string3", "string4"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to create a new list that is the combination of both inner lists:

```
["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
```

Currently, I've got something like this:

```
result = []
for inner_object in obj['outer_list']:
    for my_str in inner_object['inner_list']:
        result.append(my_str)
```

I'm wondering how to write that nested loop in a single line.

```
result = [...]
```

Comment: It can be done in a single line but it's gonna be unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterables`:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(d['inner_list'] for d in obj['outer_list']))
```

So that given:

```
obj = {
    "outer_list": [
        {
            "inner_list": ["string1", "string2"]
        },
        {
            "inner_list": ["string3", "string4"]
        }
    ]
}
```

This returns:

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4']
```

Or if you want a solution for the data you posted in the question, where the key to the inner list in each sub-dict ends with an incremental number starting from 1, you can use `enumerate` to generate such incremental numbers:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(d['inner_list_%d' % n] for n, d in enumerate(obj['outer_list'], 1)))
```

So that given:

```
obj = {
    "outer_list": [
        {
            "inner_list_1": ["string1", "string2"]
        },
        {
            "inner_list_2": ["string3", "string4"]
        }
    ]
}
```

This returns:

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4']
```

Comment: There're different keys, it's not `inner_list`.

Comment: The real question asked by the OP is how the nested loop can be rewritten into a single line, and that nested loop has a fixed key for the sub-dicts.

Comment: Very nice solution! Regarding the different keys, you can still replace it with double loop over dictionary values and it'll work for any example with static dictionary schema: `list(chain.from_iterable(val for d in obj['outer_list'] for val in d.values()))`

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution for the given input data from the OP, where keys for the inner lists end with incremental numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The nested notation in Python is the most weird i ever seen.
Its construction `[x for y in z for x in y]`

```
result = [ my_str for  inner_object in obj['outer_list'] for my_str in inner_object ['inner_list']]
```

Comment: The inner lists are numbered: `inner_list_1` and `inner_list_2`. Trying feed in the key `inner_list` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
result = []
for inner_object in obj['outer_list']:
    for k in inner_object:
        result.extend(inner_object[k])
```

Here is an one-liner :

```
result = [i for inner_object in obj['outer_list'] for v in inner_object.values() for i in v]
```

**Output** :

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I HAD to do it in one line, I'd probably do it like this.

```
import itertools
result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([tuple(el.values())[0] for el in d['outer_list']]))
```

yields

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4']
```

But the solution you already came up with is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comprehension to do it, but it runs some risks depending on the inner objects:

```
resultList = [ stringVal for stringVal in x for x in y.values() for y in obj['outer_list']]
>>> resultList
['string3', 'string3', 'string4', 'string4']
```

Comment: You have to go from largest to smallest, not smallest to largest: `[ stringVal  for y in obj['outer_list'] for x in y.values()  for stringVal in x]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to achieve this

```
from functools import reduce
result = list(reduce(lambda x,y: x['inner_list']+y['inner_list'], obj['outer_list']))
```

Answer (score 0):

`[item for inner_dict in obj["outer_list"] for item in list(inner_dict.values())[0]]`

A list comprehension is made up of two things: an expression, and a loop. You can think of a list comprehension being made as being shorthand for `list(get_items())`, where `get_items` is defined as

```
def get_items():
       loop:
            yield(expression)
```

In this case, `loop` is

```
       for inner_dict in obj["outer_list"]:
           for item in list(inner_dict.values())[0]:
```

and `expression` is `item`.

So, the format for the list comprehension is to first write what's being `yield`ed (in this case, `item`), then writing the loop that is iterated over to get those yields.

If you want, you can try it out:

```
def get_items():              
   for inner_dict in obj["outer_list"]:
       for item in list(inner_dict.values())[0]:
           yield(item)
list(get_items())
```

The loop could also have been written as

```
for inner_dict in obj["outer_list"]:
    for inner_list in list(inner_dict.values()):
        for item in inner_list:
            yield(item)
```

which would have resulted in the list comprehension

`[item for inner_dict in obj["outer_list"] for inner_list in inner_dict.values() for item in inner_list]`